# Using a language dialect in listings

Tags: listings, lstlisting

I don't understand why the following document does not compile:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, onecolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{[11]C++,[ISO]C++}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{lstlisting}[language=[11]C++]
struct test
{
    int x = 0;
};
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[language=[11]C++]` is an optional argument and `[11]` is another optional argument. In listings package, When using an optional argument inside another optional you need to use braces around the whole value.

`\begin{lstlisting}[language={[11]C++}]` ought to fix it.

If you check the listings documentation in Section 2.3 the third point in the `\itemize` explains it

> → ‘language=[77]Fortran’ does not work inside an optional argument.
>   You must put braces around the value if a value with optional argument
>   is used inside an optional argument. In the case here write
>   ‘language={[77]Fortran}’ to select Fortran 77.